# Tornado: Setting Headers for caching

Tags: tornado

I have a `tornado.web.StaticFileHandler` class that is used for serving some static content. I have noticed the images are being cached on the browser which causes image changes to go unnoticed. I have seen the solution to add a `test.jpg?<file modifier>` flag to the image to tell the browser when an image has been updated. Unfortunately I'm dealing with a lot of images and adding this flag will be expensive. I know there's another way to change the headers on the HTTP request indicating how long a browser should cache content for. Does anyone know how I can do this in Tornado with a static file handler.

Also this static file handler serves other content like .css and .js files. Is there a way to change the caching on it just for certain content or would i need to setup another static file handler and set it differently?

** Also of note is that the images are being changed by another Tornado process which I suspect why the changes aren't being picked up by the process serving the content....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a subclass of StaticFileHandler that overrides [get_cache_time](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler.get_cache_time) to return 0. That will prevent Tornado's default behavior, which is to return a cache time of 10 years for static files accessed like `file.jpg?v=random-id`.

Ignore the get_cache_time arguments (path, modified, mime_type), and just return 0.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, the function is get_cache_time(path, modified, mime_type) but the documentation doesn't state was all the arguments mean. Do you know?

Comment: Edited my answer. If you like, you can analyze the path, the file's modified date, and its mime_type before returning 0, but it sounds like you just want to return zero.

As always, you can read the source to know what the arguments mean:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L2388